# nodejs HTTP Request issue

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, httprequest

I can't seem to figure out where I'm going wrong. 
I need help determining what is causing the "[object Object]" to show up, and also the error message. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to move the bracket at the end of
`JSON.parse(data[i].zip)` 
to the left of .zip so that it looks like
 `JSON.parse(data[i]).zip`

Answer (score 0):

I think you have this errors due to vendor errors. Also responses is really non json format due '()', so just remove them.

I did only good data parser for you [here](http://code.runnable.com/VY1xMEvxCcoWRkaV/getter-of-gomashup-com-data-for-node-js-hello-world-and-response-to-question-http-stackoverflow-com-questions-31076183-nodejs-http-request-issue)

Hope this helps.